# NoMethodError in Songs#genre . Undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I'm struggling with something in my Ruby on Rails application.
This is My model:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :duration, :title, :track_URL, :genre, :image_url

end
```

I have made a new method in my `songs` controller:

```
def genre
    @songs = Song.find_all_by_genre(params[:id])
    @genre = (params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json {render json: @songs}
    end
  end
```

This is my Partial view which shows dynamically all the genres and makes them select-able:

```
<% @songs = Song.select('DISTINCT genre')%>
<li>
    <% @songs.each do |g| %>
        <a href="/genre/<%= g.genre %>"><%= g.genre %></a>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Till here everything is working , but when I select a genre  instead rendering all the songs in the `songs/genre.html.erb` view it gives me that error which I can not understand as I do have the method in the controller

```
NoMethodError in Songs#genre

Showing C:/Sites/OML/app/views/songs/genre.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h2><%= @genre %></h2>
2: 
3: <% @songs.each do |song| %>
4:     <%= song.title %>
5:     <%= song.genre %>
6: <% end %>
```

I have tried the that the same way in a brand new application and its working!!
Where could be the problem with mine ?

Comment: Did you try searching the error, "NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass"?

Comment: I did and in most of what I found the problem was missing method for the particular view or wrong typed instance variables. I`ve rechecked my code few times and all that seems to be ok. ..so I really don`t know where to look for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your partial to check if there are actually any songs, like so

```
<li>
  <% if @songs %>
    <% @songs.each do |g| %>
      <a href="/genre/<%= g.genre %>"><%= g.genre %></a>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    No songs
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Also change your `genre.html.erb` to

```
<% if @songs %>
  <% @songs.each do |song| %>
    <%= song.title %>
    <%= song.genre %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No Songs
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Luis , Ive changed my code. My partial is showing me all the existing genres, but still when I select any of them it shows me the same error. Is it possible something else in my app to make kind of conflict causing the error?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you must also change `genre.html.erb`.

Comment: Now is better , it doesn`t show the error any more, but it shows only 'No songs'. It looks like it doesn`t find or pass any songs to the view. However thank you for the help, it made some progress.